# Normative Shabbat prohibitions in Jewish Renewal

Tags: shabbat, heterodox

The Shabbat restrictions are normative in Jewish Renewal? If yes, what are the leniences in comparison with Orthodox Judaism and Conservative Judaism?

Comment: In case anyone else is like me and does not know what Jewish Renewal is see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Renewal) .

Comment: As far as I can make out, this movement is not anti-classical Shabbat observance, it's just not pro.